# GCP Storage Bucket "state-into-spec". What is that?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcp-config-connector

Using Google's Config Connector, one of the annotations is "state-into-spec".  This has no documentation and I couldn't find anything about it with a search.  Can anyone enlighten me on what this means?

https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/reference/resource-docs/storage/storagebucket#annotations

Comment: I found this documentation, which helps, but an example explaining what it is saying would be helpful: https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/concepts/managing-fields-externally#behavior_for_list_fields_in_resource_spec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a deeper search, I did manage to find the relevant documentation.  I'll post it here in case others have the same problem:

- [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/concepts/ignore-unspecified-fields)
- [Bug report](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/k8s-config-connector/issues/669)

The documentation can provide better details than I can, but in short:

- When your YAML has missing optional fields, they get populated by default values in GCP's API.
- You might not want that at times.
- There are examples in the documentation describing the implications and when you might want to change `state-into-spec`.

Comment: Yes, as an example, having "state-into-spec: merge" for StorageBucket resources without explicitly setting "withState" in the YAML can lead to issues if you are using config management tools like ArgoCD. See reference for details:

https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/concepts/ignore-unspecified-fields#resolve_fighting_between_config_management_tools_and